# how to run functions successively from a loop in an asynchronous celery task(python/flask)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, urllib

I have a function running asynchronously with Celery in a Flask application

```
task = import_files.apply_async()

@celery.task()
def import_files():
    while True:
        for filename in filenames:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(filename)
            #[...]
            aFunction(filenameFromFle)
            #[...]
            os.remove(filename)

def aFunction(filenameFromFile):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(filenameFromFile)
    parse file(xml) # xml.dom minidom
    os.remove(filenameFromFile)
```

the task is called by

> celery -A app.celery worker -l info

A file should be loaded parsed and deleted before loading the next one, which was working fine when just running as a function, but now the files are being downloaded right away and parsed simultaneously.

I created a minimal working example, but it executes successively as intended

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
TaskBase = celery.Task
class ContextTask(TaskBase):
    abstract = True
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with app.app_context():
        return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
celery.Task = ContextTask


@celery.task()
def foo():
    for x in range(1,23):
        print ('start '+str(x))
        y = bar(x)
        print ('end '+str(x))
    return "foo"

def bar(x):
    print('x= ')
    time.sleep(5);
    print(x)
    return 'baz'


task = foo.apply_async()
```

so i simplified the function for debugging

```
def bar(x):
    print('x= ')
    time.sleep(5);
    print(x)

@celery.task()
def import_files():
    while True:
        print("import data")
        utc = pytz.UTC
        filenames = get_filenames_()
        baseURL = get_baseurl_()

        for filename in filenames:
            outFilePath = filename[:-3]
            metaFile = outFilePath[:-3]+"meta"
            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(baseURL + metaFile,metaFile)
                with open(metaFile, 'r') as f:
                    first_line = f.readline()
                file_last_modified = dateutil.parser.parse(first_line[17:]).replace(tzinfo=utc)
                file_last_import = ImportDates.query.filter_by(filename=outFilePath).first()
                if (file_last_import is None):
                    bar("test")
                else:
                    file_last_import = file_last_import.last_import.replace(tzinfo=utc)
                    if file_last_import<file_last_modified:
                        bar ("test")
                os.remove(metaFile)
            except:
                pass
        print("done")
    return "1"
```

which now outputs

```
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,002: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,247: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,357: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,007: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] test
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,252: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] test
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,362: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] test
```

instead of the intended

```
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,002: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,007: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] test
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,247: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,252: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] test
[2017-05-08 14:35:27,357: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] x=
[2017-05-08 14:35:32,362: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] test
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parsed simultaneously" ? It seems to me that all files are getting downloaded, parsed, and deleted before going to the next one. Maybe you are firing the same celery task more than once ?
By the way, `import` is a really bad name for a function. You should rename it or place an underscore at the end of the function name (`import_`)

Comment: simultaniously as in: all files are downloaded and not deleted in a fraction of the time it would take to parse a single one of the files, while debug-output from the parse-function is already printed

p.s. it worked before putting it as an asynchronous function

Comment: the task running synchronously is intended, but since putting it as an asynchronous celery task filenameFromFile - files are being downloaded before "filename" from last iteration is deleted